# data not being displayed correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I submit a form using the attached code, instead of the message appearing in the div, the screen is refreshing itself and it is holding the completed form in the browser cache. I have obviously got it wrong somewhere and would be grateful if someone could point out my error. I have posted the relevant code, but if there is something I have missed, then please let me know.

In firebug, I can see the correct data that is being returned in the post tab.

I wasn't sure of the best place to post, so if this is incorrect, admin, please amend as you see fit. many thanks.

jquery code

```
//Begin function to submit report form

$(function(){         
        $(".frmreport").submit(function(){

         var formdata = $(this).serialize();

         $ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../frm10010.php",
           data: formdata,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(msg){
               $("#report_result").html("You have succesfully submitted your report. Thank you.");
          }
       });
         return false;
     });
});

// End function to submit report form
```

frm10010.php

```
<?php

     $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dept']);
     $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
     $position = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['position']);
     $feedback = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feedback']);

     $form = array('dept'=>$dept, 'name'=>$name, 'email'=>$email, 'position'=>$position, 'feedback'=>$feedback);

     $result = json_encode($form);

     echo $result;
?>
```

html

```
<div id="report_result"></div>
<div id="formShow">
          <form class=frmreport" method="post" class="webform">
            <fieldset>
            <legend><span class="subtitle">Submit Technical Report</span></legend>
            <label for="dept">Department</label>
            <input id="dept" name="dept" class="text" type="text" />
            <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" class="text" type="text" />
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" class="text" type="text" />
            <label for="position">Position:</label>
            <input id="position" name="Position" class="text" type="text" />
            <label for="feedback">Problem:</label>
            <textarea name="feedback" cols="22" rows="5"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <input class="submit" type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit Report" />
            <input class="cancel" type="reset"  name="cancel" value="Clear Report" />
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: What does the form look like ?

Comment: @adeneo I have updated code with form. Thanks

Comment: `$ajax` -> `$.ajax` : Might just be a typo but could possibily screw up form submit event.

Comment: instead of submit function make it with button click.

Comment: another typo: `<form class=frmreport"` you forgot one `"`

Comment: @Yotam Omer good spot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple of errors here

`$ajax({` should be `$.ajax({`

Second you have an error in the form class

```
<form class=frmreport" method="post" class="webform">
```

should be

```
<form class="frmreport" method="post" class="webform">
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
$(".frmreport").submit(function(){
```

Instead use

```
$("#sub_btn").click(function(){
```

And in html

```
<input class="submit" type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit Report" />
```

Change it to

```
<input class="submit" id="sub_btn" type="button"  name="submit" value="Submit Report" />
```

Another way to do it making submit handler false. But above solution will work here. There is also . is missing in ajax call.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to listen for submit events on the form rather then a click event on a button. There are more than one way to submit a form ?